# Implementing "macros" TypeScript transformer

Tags: typescript, macros, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to implement the following "macros" transformer in TypeScript. I'd like to expand a definition like:

```
class SourceClass {
    @lazy
    lazyProperty    : Map<number, string>       = new Map()
}
```

to:

```
class SourceClass {
    $lazyProperty   : Map<number, string>       = undefined

    get lazyProperty () : Map<number, string> {
        if (this.$lazyProperty !== undefined) return this.$lazyProperty

        return this.$lazyProperty = new Map()
    }

    set lazyProperty (value : Map<number, string>) {
        this.$lazyProperty = value
    }
}
```

And I want to make the `$lazyProperty` property to be available for the rest of the program (to be able to check the lazy value presence). So, for example, I'd like this code to typecheck correctly, even that `$lazyProperty` is generated in the "macros":

```
class SourceClass {
    @lazy
    lazyProperty    : Map<number, string>       = new Map()

    method () {
        if (this.$lazyProperty !== undefined) { ... }
    }
}
```

For that I need the transformation to happen *before* the type-checking stage in compiler's pipeline, which, as I figured out after some research, is not how the regular transformers works.

However, if I'm correct, there are various workarounds, the most advanced is `ts-morph`, but I'm looking for something that is compatible with `ts-patch` and preferable something that integrates well with the IDE language services.

Can someone experienced with this kind of transformers outline the implementation plan? Perhaps there's a working example somewhere? (there has to be one, macros transformation should be a quite common requirement).

So far what I found is something related to overriding the `CompilerHost`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147818/365104 but its far from complete example.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Magically, I can't find our conversation with cronoik here anymore. Wonder why. @cronoik You wouldn't be removing it silently, right?

Comment: Your comments were removed by a moderator because such discussions shouldn't be held at SO. As already suggested previously, please open a discussion on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Here ya go -- this works great! https://github.com/GoogleFeud/ts-macros